# the rewards / loyalty program is dishing out free money to everybody

Tags: php, e-commerce, modulo, reward-system

My application rewards loyalty by printing a coupon code on the receipt / thank you page every 15th order. The coupon value is equal to the total price of one of the previous 15 orders, pulled at random.

This was working for a while, but now for some reason, every new user is getting a coupon code on their very first order:

```
$count = dbFuncs::countRewardsProgress($_SESSION['user_id'])['count'];
$displayRewardsCode = dbFuncs::displayRewardsCode()['rewardsCode'];

        if ( $count > 0 ) {
            $remainder = $count % 15;
        }


        if($remainder == 0) {

            echo "Congratulations, You've earned a $$previousOrderValueRoulette coupon code! We thank you for your continued business.";
            echo "<br />";
            echo "<br />";
            echo 'Coupon code: ';
            echo $displayRewardsCode;

            dbFuncs::assignRewardsCode($previousOrderValueRoulette, $_SESSION['user_id'], $displayRewardsCode);

        } else {
            echo 'rewards progress: ';
            echo $count;
            echo '/15 orders completed';
        }
```

How can I ensure that customers only receive a coupon every 15th order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because if `$count` is 0, `$reminder` is not initialized, so it is equal to 0 in your next condition.

To solve, change the second condition to also check that `$count` is greater than 0

```
    if ( $count > 0 ) {
        $remainder = $count % 15;
    }


    if($count > 0 && $remainder == 0) {

        echo "Congratulations, You've earned a $$previousOrderValueRoulette coupon code! We thank you for your continued business.";
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<br />";
        echo 'Coupon code: ';
        echo $displayRewardsCode;

        dbFuncs::assignRewardsCode($previousOrderValueRoulette, $_SESSION['user_id'], $displayRewardsCode);

    } else {
        echo 'rewards progress: ';
        echo $count;
        echo '/15 orders completed';
    }
```